# wxPython not showing grid

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython to make a gui. Currently I have a menubar, and three panels. I want to have a grid show up in the second panel when I click a button. However. When I click on the button, all I get is a small grey rectangle.

Here is the code for the button:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCo, id=self.submit.GetId())
```

and here is the code for the "OnCo" event when the button is clicked:

```
def OnCo(self, e):

    #to get rid of stuff that was previously in the panel
    for child in self.panel2.GetChildren(): 
        child.Destroy() 
    for child in self.panel3.GetChildren(): 
        child.Destroy()  

    mygrid = gridlib.Grid(self.panel2, -1)
    mygrid.CreateGrid(500,7)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(mygrid, -1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.panel2.SetSizer(sizer)
    mygrid.SetColLabelValue(0, 'S')
    mygrid.SetColLabelValue(1, 'PB')
    mygrid.SetColLabelValue(2, 'P')
    mygrid.SetColLabelValue(3, 'T')
    mygrid.SetColLabelValue(4, 'D')
```

Any help on how I can get my grid to show? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the grid is not sizing correctly; your items may be there, but it's not showing everything. After changing values in a grid, I always make sure to update the sizing of it. I usually just add a simple function to the class like this:

`def SetGridSize(self):
    self.mygrid.AutoSizeRows()
    self.mygrid.AutoSizeColumns()
    self.sizer.Fit(self)`

and then call SetGridSize() whenever I change the values to make sure the whole thing shows on the screen instead of getting cut off.

Of course, you'll have to adapt it a bit to your names and whatnot. This implementation assumes the class is a wx.Frame object.